# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sushi

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate, maven

I have a web application using a jar file(lib) to access a Database.
The jar file when used as a standalone application executes correctly but the webapp received the error:

`[01-08-12 13:17:05] - 35266 WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001`

`java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myapp`

I have read the answers to similar questions but none of them solve my problem.

I am using Maven, where I have added the dependency for the mysql version I am using, 5.1.21. In fact, I have added it for both the Lib and the Webapp.

Before that, I tried to define in Eclipse a Connectivity Driver Definition bound to the same file, that I had copied to WEB-INF/lib in the eclipse project for my Webapp and with the same parameters that I include below for the persistence.xml file

I am not using any java to configure since I do all the configuration in the persistence.xml file(that I have copied to both META-INF folders, the one for the app(lib) and the one for the webapp. I am using Hibernate (4.1.2) through JPA.

The persistence.xml file is like that:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="myappPersistenceUnit"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider> org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myapp" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit> 

</persistence>
```

the exception that I get is at Runtime, when launching an Http Request to the app, not at the initialization of the webapp, where I haven't seen any errors but this warning appears:

> [01-08-12 13:16:39] - 8782 WARN 
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl  - HHH000342:
>   Could not obtain connection to query metadata : No suitable driver
>   found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myapp

I guess this is due to the information being looked up from the database is not necessary at init, and no exception is thrown but the same root cause in both cases.

EDIT:I am using Tomcat 6.0

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check your classpath?

Comment: Please add what application server you are using

Comment: @Kayser , the classpath shouldn't be managed by tomcat and maven? (I am checking in the meanwhile)

Comment: @Kayser, I do have the mysql-connector included in Java Build Path->Libraries via the Apache-Tomcat v6.0 as I have copied the file to TOMCAT_HOME\lib. Is this what you refer to or maybe I should set a system variable to point also to TOMCAT_HOME\lib?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are missing MySql driver in your project. To solve this you need to add  mysql-connector.jar. externally to your project. 
Or if you are using a maven project then use the following dependency in your pom.xml file.

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.4</version>
  </dependency>
```

You can use a suitable version if needed!!

Answer (score 1):

If you're running your application as a Java Application, Add the JAR file in the Java Build Path, in Eclipse.

Alternatively, I wouldn't put the MSQL jar inside `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your web project, instead, I would put it in your Application folder library folder, where the Application Server will load your driver and you can access it from the Application Server container.

Comment: my webapp has the lib as a jar file in the java  build path. Also, when adding the Maven dependency for the mysql I removed it from the web-inf/lib folder

Comment: @Picarus, follow this advice. Put the MySQL dependency as "provided" in Maven and copy the MySQL jar under `TOMCAT_HOME`/server/lib

Comment: @mavroprovato, I have addded the library (with provided) to TOMCAT_HOME/lib that is the existing folder in my version. Same error. Is the folder the same? I tried both options and they fail.

Comment: My bad, TOMCAT_HOME/lib is the correct location. Indeed, the problem is very weird. Maybe you should try with a fresh installation of Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

you should put mysql connector jar with your own code & add jar file with your project.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem some time before, but I solved that issue. There may be different reasons for this exception.

One of them may be that the `jar` you are adding to your `lib` folder may be old. Try to find out the **latest mysql-connector-jar version** and add that to your `classpath`. It may solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Tomcat 9. Solved by not having the driver jar in both common/lib and WEB-INF/lib (used the former).